# Finding the spectral decomposition of $\Delta= \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

What is the spectral decomposition  of the operator $\Delta= \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ in $(L^{2}(\mathbb R), dx)$?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator $\Delta = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ has a natural domain $\mathcal{D}(L)\subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all twice absolutely continuous functions $f \in L^2$ for which $f'' \in L^2$. On this domain, $\Delta$ is selfadjoint in the strictest sense. The spectral resolution of the identity for this selfadjoint operator is
$$
    E(S)f=   \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\chi_{\{s : s^2 \in S\}}\mathcal{F}(f)),
$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is the inverse Fourier transform on $L^2$. For example, the spectrum of $\Delta$ is $[0,\infty)$ and
\begin{align}
        E[0,t]f & = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\chi_{[-\sqrt{t},\sqrt{t}]}\mathcal{F}(f)) \\
 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sqrt{t}}^{\sqrt{t}}e^{isx}\hat{f}(s)ds \\
 &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\int_{-\sqrt{t}}^{\sqrt{t}}e^{is(x-y)}dsdy \\
 &=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\frac{\sin(\sqrt{t}(y-x))}{y-x}dy
\end{align}
This is classically defined for $0 < t < \infty$ and $f \in L^2$.

Comment: @ TrialAndError, thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Z.Alfata : You're welcome. Note that I just changed the definition of $\Delta$ in my problem because $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ has positive spectrum, which is what I wanted. And that's because $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ is selfadjoint and its square is $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$.